# SVNPath is ignored in Location in Apache configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-dav-svn

There are many SVN repositories all hosted under the same directory. I would like to expose one of them (`extra`) to people with different credentials.

Why does the following apache configuration does not work for `http://example.net/svn/extra` but works for all the other SVN repos like `http://example.net/svn/proj1`.

The error I get when I attempt a checkout of `http://example.net/svn/extra` is:

```
[error] [client x.x.x.x] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/home/trac/svn/svn/format': No such file or directory
[error] [client x.x.x.x] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[error] [client x.x.x.x] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
[error] [client x.x.x.x] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
```

Please note that subversion tries to access `/home/trac/`**`svn/svn`**`/format`. Where does the `svn/svn` path come from?

This is the configuration:

```
    <Location /svn/extra>
            DAV svn
            SVNPath /home/trac/svn/extra
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName "DevsExtra"
            AuthUserFile /home/trac/devs-extra.digest
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /svn>
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /home/trac/svn/
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName "Devs"
            AuthUserFile /home/trac/devs.digest
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using multiple Apache locations to handle authentication, I'd suggest taking a look at `mod_authz_svn` for Apache since it's designed for access control on a per-path basis. This way you can do something like the following to give a subset of developers access to that folder:

```
[groups]
devs-extra = bob, bill, jim, sally

[svn:/extra]
@devs-extra = rw
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html